# How to disable internal sound card in Ubuntu?

Tags: sound, soundcard

I'm a first time Ubuntu user as of today. I've installed on an old laptop of mine, [a Compal FL90](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Review-Compal-FL90-Notebook.4209.0.html).

I forgot until this new install that the internal sound card is faulty and makes a nasty high-pitch squealing sound. I remedied this before by disabling it in device manager on Windows, but I have no idea how to go about doing it in Ubuntu.

Would anyone be able to help with this?

Comment: **That's easy: blacklist the module and reboot!** (vague question = vague answer)  What's the manufacturer/model of the card?  Could you go to a Terminal by pressing [Ctrl][Alt][T] and type `hardinfo --generate-report > /tmp/hardinfo.txt` and upload /tmp/hardinfo.txt to http://paste.ubuntu.com and provide the link back here...  We'll take it from there if you also need to provide a `lspci` or `lsusb`

Comment: Hey Thanks very much for the reply. I have actually tried a different approach, which is just physically removing the audio board. My laptop is in bits currently, but hopefully upon putting it back together, the problem will be permanently resolved. If not, I will definitely do what you've suggested and get back to you. Thanks again!